# CSS Positioning problem (understanding floats margin-left/right/auto)

Tags: css

Its not letting me post an image but here it is if you can see this: http://i49.photobucket.com/albums/f272/huntmur/DIV-QUES.gif

I think this will be more clear,

D2,D3 & D4 have be next to each other and centered on the screen at all times.(960px)
         **D2-680px, D3-10px, D4-270px** (all three together & must be centered on screen)
D1 and D5 must adjust according to the screen width.

Also, if the users browser width is greater that 1200px, the D1 **will also be used**.

Ive only included a D5 here for centering purposes (because unfortunately I am only thinking
in terms of tables.  D5 wont really be used.)

To help you understand better, I have a sticky notes app I wrote and want to put on the site. Normally all notes have to stay inside the 680 div but if their browser is 1200px I 
want to allow them to put them in the left column(D1) as well.

So what I was thinking of doing(as a work around) is centering the three columns with the code I have above (the 960 area)..and, I would just layer on a div(D1) if the browser-width is 1200px at least.  [My calc for the d1 layer width would be (browserWidth-960/2)].

```
<style>
    BODY {margin:0px;padding:0px;}<BR>
    #container {width:960px;margin-left:auto;padding:0px;margin-right:auto;height:60px;}<BR>
    #dx {width:690px;}<BR>
    #d2 {background-color:#ff0000;margin:0px;padding:0px;width:680px;height:60px;}<BR>
    #d3 {background-olor:#00ff00;margin:0px;padding:0px;width:10px;height:60px;float:right;}<BR>
    #d4 {background-color:#0000ff;margin:0px;padding:0px;width:270px;height:60px;float:right;}<BR>
</style>

<div id="container"><BR>
  <div id="d4"><BR>
   &nbsp;<BR>
  </div><BR>
  <div id="dx"><BR>
      <div id="d3"><BR>
       &nbsp;<BR>
      </div><BR>
      <div id="d2"><BR>
       &nbsp;<BR>
      </div><BR>
  </div><BR>
```

In other words, I can't mess with the 960 area (as that's the site) but if their screen is wide enough, I also want to let them put the stickys on the left side column(D1) as well.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for well enough to attempt this. This bit specifically is confusing: `"Also, the D1 will be used if the users browser width is greater that 1200px"`. Could you try to explain some more? Perhaps an image, or the equivalent `table` based HTML if you have it?

Comment: It's your question — please edit it and add additional code as such and preferably formatted instead of posting it in the comments.

Comment: Here is what I did in:
http://jsfiddle.net/huntmur/QJBJz/

This takes care of the 960 so maybe the best way is just to layer on the D1 in the top-left of the screen???  Otherwise, I dont think I can guarantee the 960 would be centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think either of these ideas is *exactly* what you wanted, but hopefully one of them is close enough.

**Idea #2:** http://jsfiddle.net/DXmLE/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="d1">d1</div>
    <div id="d2">d2</div>
    <div id="d3">d3</div>
    <div id="d4">d4</div>
    <div id="d5">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed
}
#container > div {
    display: table-cell;
    height:60px
}
#d1, #d5 {
    overflow: hidden
}
#d2 {
    background-color: #f00;
    width: 680px
}
#d3 {
    background-color: #0f0;
    width: 10px
}
#d4 {
    background-color: #00f;
    width: 270px;
}
```

<strike>**Idea #1:** http://jsfiddle.net/PnujB/</strike>

If either of those are acceptable, I will update my answer with the corresponding HTML/CSS.

Comment: Actually, IDEA #2 seems to be working.. trying to drop it in now.

Comment: (sorry i did mean #2 -- and it is working GREAT!  Please update)

Comment: I'll switch it in a few minutes.